# Eclipse renaming function on projects with dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, refactoring, rename

I have two eclipse project. The second one depends on the first one. When I try to rename a java class of the first project (using the rename function on the java file on the project explorer) it correctly do the refactor of that project but it doesn't changes anything  on the project that depends on it.

Is there a way in eclipse to tell the renaming function to act even on the projects that are linked to the refactored one? Thanks for help.

My Eclipse version is Juno.

**Update:**
Forgot to mention that the projects are linked to an SVN repository. Maybe it could be relevant.

**Update 2:**
I add more details after mliebelt request of clarification.
My Eclipse version is Juno, Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, build id: 20120614-1722.

I've installed some plugins: subclipse, JRebel, m2e, Eclipse Web Tool Platform.
The second project is linked to the first one as a project dependency in eclipse. I have added the first project in the project tab of Java Build Path. Everything seems to work fine, even the renaming function.

Then, I tried to put the two project in two different SVN repositories. I created two repositories on the SVN server and I installed on my machine the client tortoiseSVN and the eclipse plugin subclipse. Since I didn't succeeded in importing the projects on the server directly from eclipse, I copied the projects' folders in a different location and I removed the projects from eclipse. I used tortoiseSVN to import the projects, each one on a repository with the same name of the project, and than I imported the project back to eclipse. To do that I used the eclipse "import existent project into workspace" function with the "copy project into workspace" option selected. Everything seems to work but not the renaming function.

Comment: I expect this should work. How are the projects linked? As project dependency in eclipse or by maven?

Comment: I expect this should work too. They're linked as a project dependency in eclipse.

Comment: can you make sure that the project is listed under the projects tab of the Java build path in Eclipse?

Comment: The only reason I could think of this not working is that the dependency is broken somewhere, maybe there is a class that was overwritten in your second project.  Have you tried refactoring the other way around (from the second project instead of the first or vice-versa)?

Comment: @Farlan Yes, I tried. The result is the same. I also tried to remove the link to the source folder in the Source tab of Java build path but nothing changed.

Comment: "the link in the source folder" make me wonder how you've set up the two projects; it sounds suspicious. Can you describe in detail or post  screen shots of the Java Build Path of both projects?

Comment: Also try this: Assuming ProjectA is the "first" one with the code you want to refactor, and ProjectB is the one that depends on ProjectA. In ProjectB, go to where you're using the class from ProjectA, put your cursor on a method or class name from ProjectA, hit F3. It should take you to the code in ProjectA. If it doesn't, something is amiss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work (for me), so here is what I have done to reproduce the behavior. I hope that this helps to find the error.

1. Create two projects, and make the second dependent on the first. [image: Java Build Path for <code>Test2</code>]
2. Create some source code, so that you can refactor it. Ensure that a class in `Test2` is dependent on a class in `Test`.
3. Select from the context menu of the method you want to rename. Enter there a new name for the method, only then is the `Preview` option available. Ensure that `Update references` is checked. [image: Rename a method clarification dialog]
4. Press the button `Preview` to see which classes will be changed by the refactoring. [image]

As you can see, it works for me. Please check what is different in your context:

- Define dependency different
- Use different refactoring (which possibly contains a bug)
- ... ?

I then added the two projects to a (local) repository (I use the plugin Subversive, it that matters), and have retried the refactoring, and it works the same way. What is that "it does not work if the projects are in SVN"? The projects have to be in Eclipse, refactoring cannot be done on the Subversion repository directly.

---

I have made another attempt to reproduce the error, but could not. Here is what has worked for me (no screenshots included):

1. Installed Java EE from Eclipse (version Indigo)
2. Installed Subclipse 1.8 from the Eclipse Marketplace.
3. Defined the 2 projects as before.
4. Added the projects to the different Subversion repositories by using `Team > Share Project...> SVN > select the repository location > Finish`
5. I have then deleted the 2 projects, and instantiated them inside the workspace by doing the following steps:

   - Go to the `SVN Repository Exploring perspective`.
   - Open in the view `SVN Repositories` your repository locations, and select for each project from the menu `Checkout...`.
   - The projects will be reinstantiated insided the workspace, and the dependency between the 2 is not lost.
6. After that, I am able to rename a method as I have shown above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what I have done. It works if the project is on eclipse but it doesn't work for my projects on SVN. I think I should add some dependencies between the SVN repositories.

Comment: What does is mean: "it doesn't work for my projects on SVN"? I don't understand your current situation.

Comment: I removed my project from SVN, checked all the dependencies, and the renaming function worked correctly. When I put my projects back to the SVN server, the refactoring doesn't work as expected anymore. Really don't know why, since I'm very new to SVN.

Comment: Could you please be more specific in your question? All these details have to go there. Explain how you "put my projects back to the SVN server", there are trillions of options how to do that. Please add: version info for Eclipse, Subversion, plugins used in Eclipse, ... We are willing to help you, but you should give us more information ...

Comment: I accept your answer and try to ask something more specific about SVN dependencies. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I will followup with a new setup, like you described. I think the problem lays in not using Eclipse to import the projects ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my workflow, described in Update2, was that, when I imported back the projects to eclipse, I used "import existent project into workspace" function.

I had to use SVN **Checkout Projects from SVN** instead, choosing the repositories I previously created.

[image]

Comment: @mliebelt Hope this is interesting also for you! :)